# Updating a variable from a function in a different file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to keep the value of a variable between files on a python script. The end goal is to separate functions from an algorithm.

The function is very simple - I have saved it in a file called test:

```
def tests(x):
    global y
    x=10

    y=x
    return y
```

Then the algorithm part is again simple - saved in a different file, called test1:

```
import test as t
y=0
t.tests(y)
print("new value is "+str(y))
```

However, the value does not seem to be updated to 10 - it keeps its initial value of 0.

I am sure I am missing sth very obvious, but could you pls help?

The above code works if I contain the function and the algorithm parts in the same fie, but I would like to separate them.

Thank you

Comment: You have to assign the value `t.tests(y)` to the variable y to update it. Try changing the line to `y = t.tests(y)`

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty minute, the only reason the value is not updated is because you forgot to assign the value to the variable `y`
The code in the second file(test1) should be:

```
import test as t
y = 0
y = t.tests(y)
print("New value is " + str(y))
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it was driving me crazy! Works great now